# Regular expression to get last occurence until next char

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to work out this regular expression and stuck - can anyone help.

I have a string:

**"This is a string with a [flag NO MATCH] that should match [flag THIS] but dont want this [NO NO]"**

I want to capture the last occurance of flag enclosed in brackets.

Tried this:

```
\[flag(?!.*\[flag)(.*)\]
```

I am almost there, however this matches everything up to the last "]" in the string.  How can I get it to only match up to the next "]" following the match.

**Want to match this**: "THIS"

**Get this**: "THIS] but dont want this [NO NO"

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `*` as non-greedy,

```
\[flag(?!.*\[flag)(.*?)\]
```

OR

```
\[flag(?!.*\[flag)\s*([^\]]*)\]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xV3aC4/1)

Comment: Plus 1, also to avoid space in captured group: `\[flag (?!.*\[flag)(.*?)\]`

Comment: As simple as that.  I knew it would be.  Thanks so much for your help.